# How to show conditional regions in Omega subtheme

Tags: theming

I have created omega sub theme and in that sub theme i have region called postscript where there are four blocks are rendering.
 If there are only two blocks then the other two should take 50%-50% width.
what is the best way to do this?

Now i tried print render ($page['postscript_first']); for printing only postscript_first but it does not show anything(i have attached block to it in my block settings page).

Also i tried region.tpl.php for modification in my sub theme template folder.
I did't get how to print a single region as there is only print $content statement in my region.tpl.php file.

Comment: Hard to say from here, but check `count(element_children($page['postscript_first']))`, that'll give you the number of blocks in the region. From there you can just assign different classes to your HTML and use CSS to set the width